# Get list of all blocked and allowed sites from 'content settings/notifications ' section in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

Is there any way to get the list of all the blocked and unblocked URLs for which notifications are blocked/allowed in chrome. Can it be done through api?

Comment: [Apparently](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#type-ContentSetting) we can only query by an individual URL.